# Template of theorem statement?

Tags: lists, positioning

So Basically I am looking for something that looks like this:

Using the amsmath package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\left. \begin{aligned}
       A &= T \\
       B &= F 
    \end{aligned} \right\} \implies A \vee B = T \vee F = T$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Where we have multiple premises of the theorem on the left joined by a bracket, and we have (multiple) conclusions of the theorem on the right. Two sides connected by an arbitrary operator (in this case would be the arrow).

The thing that isn't working with this template is that it should:

1. divides the page into left and right region, i.e. when new line is created, the content of the right region will not occupy that of the left.
2. must allow itemized/enumerated list on both sides, which means the template cannot be in math mode.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: By the way, that is semantically grotesque!

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: sorry about that... I have corrected the code

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to accomplish what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left.\begin{aligned}
    A &= T \\
    B &= F 
  \end{aligned}\right\}
  \implies
  A \vee B = T \vee F = T
\]

\[
  \left.\begin{aligned}
    A &= T \\
    B &= F 
  \end{aligned}\right\}
  \implies 
  \left\{\begin{aligned}
    A \vee B &= T \\
    C \vee D &= F \\
    E \vee F &= T
  \end{aligned}\right.
\]

\[
  \left.\begin{tabular}{@{\textbullet\hspace{1em}}p{5cm}}
    First item \\
    Second item that is longer \\
    Last item that is very long and spans more than a single line
  \end{tabular}\right\}
  \implies 
  \left\{\begin{aligned}
    A \vee B &= T \\
    C \vee D &= F \\
    E \vee F &= T
  \end{aligned}\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) allows for a "falsified" `itemize` within a (text-mode) `tabular`. You can also use an `itemize`, as long as you use a `p{<len>}` column specification.